# Checkmate about TLS certificates on local networks, self-signed certificates and CA

Tags: vpn, ssl, certificate, https, tls

I know barely anything regarding SSL and TLS certificates. Sorry about that.

This is what my company asked me:

1. They need to put a server on the local network that will be accessible through VPN to people around the country.
2. They want this server to communicate using HTTPS.
3. They want the server to have a TLS certificate created by a certified CA.
4. They tell me that the server is an Microsoft IIS server.

What I have discovered so far:

1. it is impossible to have a SSL certificate created by a certified CA for an intranet server which address is `server.mydomain.local` and not accessible from the internet.
2. The only way to have a SSL certificate for that server will be a self-signed certificate, but these certificates are not famous to be trustable by things like iOS and etc. iOS hates self-signed certificates and their stuff is basically iOS devices accessing a local server.

What I need is confirmation that I am right or if not, how to solve this checkmate.

thanks

Comment: I've not tried it before, but you can create a MS CA server on your network, establish the certs you need, and then have your users install the CA Signing and any intermediary certs on the VPN'd hosts. Alternately, if your VPN'd users are resolving via your internal DNS servers (as is common), you can host a zone for a domain other than the internal domain, so you could get a cert for your public domain, install it on the server, add an internal zone for that domain with a A rec for your server, and have people use that domain to access the server's services.

Comment: the thing you need to keep in mind is that the browser does all the work here, and its connectivity is established by the VPN, so as long as the domain you are browsing matches the cert, and the cert comes from a CA the browser trusts, thats all that matters. you could actually have different sites on the same FQDN (one public, one private), running the same cert, and switch which one you are using by turning the VPN on or off. not saying thats a good idea, but it is possible if you can control the dns resolution of the client on VPN connect.

Comment: Public users or staff?

Comment: "not accessible from the internet." - Except it will be accessible to the internet?  This sounds like a perfect case for a Let's Encrypt certificate. Let's Certificate is trusted by all major browsers on all major platforms by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that public CAs will only issue certificates to public domain names (as that's what they're able to verify). However, you're missing that this doesn't necessarily have anything to do with whether the server is publicly accessible or not, nor even with whether it has a public IP address or not. **The server does not have to *be* public in order to have a public domain name.**

The CA is only concerned with verifying the ownership of the name that'll be in the URL. *Some* CAs, such as Let's Encrypt, typically do so by connecting to the server via HTTP (though that's not the only option anymore). But many other CAs will allow you to verify just the ownership of whole domain (possibly through Whois records) and then freely issue certificates for any subdomain, even subdomains which don't have a web server, or those which don't have anything publicly accessible, or indeed even subdomains which don't exist at all.

So I assume the company already has a website and therefore a public domain name. There are several ways you could go about it, depending on what the company is comfortable with:

- You could have the server use a regular public IP address and put it in DNS like you always would... and just make the server reject all connections not made through the VPN, for example, using Windows Firewall or some IIS-specific settings.

  (Most VPN systems can be configured to route any IP address range through the secure tunnel, it doesn't matter whether the IP addresses are "public" or "private". Routing the company's public IP range through the corp VPN is a normal thing to do.)
- You can create a subdomain which points to an internal IP address – for example, `server.corp.mydomain.com` can be a public subdomain which points to 192.168.7.1, a private IP address that's only accessible through a VPN – and that still won't prevent it from having a publicly valid HTTPS certificate issued.

  (This doesn't need anything special in terms of DNS setup, you can literally just point a domain at any address you want.)
- You could have the actual web server at a private IP address, but use a "reverse proxy" frontend server at a public IP address. The reverse proxy could handle IP-based access as well as SSO or password authentication. It could even handle the Let's Encrypt HTTP-based certificate issuance on behalf of the real private server.

  (We use this method to provide secure HTTPS access to some rusty old webapps – one of them still runs on Server 2003 and could not handle modern browsers at all, instead the reverse proxy provides the necessary TLS 1.2 support as well as SAML authentication.)

(There are other options as well. In addition to public CAs, anyone can make their own CA and most corporate networks running Microsoft AD will actually have one – the only problem is getting devices to trust that CA, but for corporate issued iPhones that should be easy to do through whatever "mobile device management" system the company is using. Though don't tell people to install a company CA on personal systems...)

Comment: `The server does not have to be public in order to have a public domain name.` what? Do you mean I can have www.mysite.com on an intranet? My company has a public domain, like `example.com` but they have configured a local server like `server.mydoman.local` that is only accessible through VPN. Notice this domain has nothing to do with their main one and is not publicly accessible. My problem, like you said, is getting the iPhone to trust that certificate and establish a secure connection.

Comment: @Duck: Yes, I do mean you can have `www.mysite.com` on an intranet, or wherever else you want it. I've seen that you mentioned "server.mydoman.local" previously, but you didn't say it was a _requirement_ to use the .local name (and indeed you cannot get publicly issued certificates for a .local name).

Comment: so you need to understand that the domain name only points to a server's IP. if you ask an internal DNS server for www.mysite.com you might get back 10.0.0.59 and that same query against a public DNS server might return 18.2.5.4 or it might return a NXDomain error, because the public DNS server doesn't have a registration for that name. by hosting a zone on your internal DNS servers for mysite.com and putting in a A rec for www in it that points to 10.0.0.59, you can use the name www.mysite.com to reach the internal server, provided the VPN is on and you resolve with your internal dns server

Comment: @FrankThomas: That's true, but... a public DNS server might return 10.0.0.59 as well, there's nothing in DNS that would forbid it.

Comment: right, but who would care since the site is available on VPN only? I was just pointing out that the response to a query is relative to the DNS server queried, and that the connectivity of the client affects this. servers can have multiple names, and names on different servers can have different addresses. if the domain need exist to get the cert, then that requirement is fufilled, and nothing else particularly matters, right?

Comment: @user1686 - when you type www.something.com the browser has to get the nameservers from the registar and when you buy a .com name or whatever, you have to configure the registrar with nameservers that are public. I don't see how you can have a tld on an intranet server. Yes, their servers have the .local suffix.

Comment: @Duck: Nameservers themselves have to be public, doesn't mean they can return answers pointing at addresses which aren't public.

Comment: It seems like we're not talking about public nameservers, but private ones, inside the network the users VPN'd into. we need a public name on a public zone to get the cert, but the actual use of the name by clients will be processed by the VPN'd (internal/private) networks DNS servers. Op, Does your network does have an internal DNS server for resolving internal names? @user1686, I'll bow out if I'm being a distraction, but it seems like the the key question is which server holds a usable host address for users in the correct connected state (ie VPN'd in to the internal network at Layer2/3).

Comment: @FrankThomas: I guess when you say "if the domain need exist to get the cert" you're talking about LE-style HTTP based validation? (i.e. having the domain externally point to a public server that handles the LE challenges, while internally it points to the real webapp?) That's the only case where I could see it being useful for OP to have split public/internal DNS views...

Comment: the value to internal DNS, is that the site is only to be accessible to the LAN, and clients that have VPN'd onto that LAN. when the VPN adapter pulls DHCP info from the VPN gateway, including the routes and internal DNS servers for the LAN. the actual server never need be accessible from outside. set up the subdomain on the server and the internal DNS server as a new zone, and then issue a CSR from IIS using the registered domain in order to purchase the cert. Thats my take on it anyway.